# SolrCloud's Cluster status API returns internal kubernetes hostnames which can't be reached from outside the kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, solr, kubernetes-helm, solrj, solrcloud

I setup SolrCloud cluster using [helm chart](https://hub.helm.sh/charts/incubator/solr) on Kubernetes cluster and  exposed the solr-svc as NodePort i.e.,

`service/solr-svc  NodePort  10.252.234.133   <none>   8983:32470/TCP`

I get the following error message with apache Solrj client.

`Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Tried fetching cluster state using the node names we knew of, i.e. [solr-2.solr-headless.default:8983_solr, solr-0.solr-headless.default:8983_solr, solr-1.solr-headless.default:8983_solr]. However, succeeded in obtaining the cluster state from none of them.`

This is because, SolrCloud's Cluster status API returns the following response when queried for cluster status

```
live_nodes: [
"solr-2.solr-headless.default:8983_solr",
"solr-0.solr-headless.default:8983_solr",
"solr-1.solr-headless.default:8983_solr"]
```

API I used for fetching the cluster status: `http://<k8snodeIP:NodePort>/solr/admin/collections?action=CLUSTERSTATUS`

Basically it returns the k8s internal cluster hostnames and those can’t be reached from outside the cluster.

May I know how to fix it. Thank you very much.

Comment: The easy fix is probably to use http with a load balancer to access the nodes that way instead, but yes, going through Zookeeper would be more ideal. There seems to be someone who has looked into this exact issue in https://medium.com/lenskart-engineering/cdp-part-2-moving-solrcloud-to-kubernetes-using-helm-6943e60a61c5

Comment: @chakra Does the comment above solve your problem?

Comment: @MatsLindh thanks for the suggestion. using zookeeper also results in same problem. I am trying to run solr indexing jobs also within the k8s cluster now.